# Rewrite object's constructor's prototype doesn't work

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here is my code:

```
function Class() {};

Class.prototype.extend = function () {
    var instance = new Class();
    instance.constructor.prototype = {
        say: function () {
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    }
    console.log(instance); //Class {extend: function}
}

Class.extend = function () {
    this.prototype.extend();
}

Class.extend();
```

In the `extend` method, I rewrite an instance's prototype `instance.constructor.prototype =  {..}`,

however, when I log the instance, it doesn't show the `say` method

Why the rewrite doesn't work? How can I let it work?

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/vpkTG/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You successfully changed `Class.prototype`, but you changed it to a *totally different object*.

`instance` has a reference to its prototype object, called `instance.__proto__`. When a new `Class` instance is created, the `__proto__` of the instance points to the same object as  `Class.prototype`.

However, your change *what* `Class.prototype` *refers to*. This will affect the `__proto__` of future instances, but not of any *existing instances*. `instance.__proto__` still points to the old object that `Class.prototype` used to refer to.

This is how it looks at first, after `instance` is constructed:

```
instance.__proto__ ===> { extend: function } <=== Class.prototype
```

This is how it looks after assignment of `Class.prototype` to a new object:

```
instance.__proto__ ===> { extend: function }
                        { say:    function } <=== Class.prototype
```

**Instead**, you want to *modify* the object `Class.prototype` refers to:

```
instance.constructor.prototype.say = function () {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

That will get you a final picture like this:

```
instance.__proto__ ===> { extend: function, say: function } <=== Class.prototype
```

See that `Class.prototype` and `instance.__proto__` still point to the same object, but the object itself now has an additional property.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a new prototype object only newly instantiated objects will have the new prototype:

```
function Class() {};

Class.prototype.extend = function () {
    var instance = new Class();
    instance.constructor.prototype = {
        say: function () {
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    }
    console.log(instance);    //Class {extend: function}
    console.log(new Class()); //Class {say: function}
}

Class.extend = function () {
    this.prototype.extend();
}

Class.extend();
```

This is because the reference to the prototype object is copied from the constructor's prototype at the time the object is instantiated. If you want to add to the prototype of all existing instances and future instance you can just modify the prototype object rather than assigning a whole new object to the constructor:

```
function Class() {};

Class.prototype.extend = function () {
    var instance = new Class();
    instance.constructor.prototype.say = function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
    delete instance.constructor.prototype.extend;
    console.log(instance); //Class {say: function}
}

Class.extend = function () {
    this.prototype.extend();
}

Class.extend();
```

Answer (score 0):

I does add this function. But you are changing the `prototype` object itself, rather than changing its properties:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vpkTG/3/)

```
Class.prototype.extend = function () {
    var instance = new Class();
    instance.constructor.prototype.say =
        function () {
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    console.log(instance);
    // Class {extend: function, say: function}

}
```

When you're trying to access `some_obj.some_field` the JS engine itself will first check objects own properties and then will go to `some_obj.prototype` and look for `some_field`.

By assigning `instance.constructor.prototype = {...}` you are changing where `prototype` will point for all newly created objects, but not for already existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Though a non-standard approach, this will help you incase 
the JS environment allows you to 
    edit **proto** internal property.

```
function Class() {};

Class.prototype.extend = function () {
    var instance = new Class();
    instance.__proto__ = instance.constructor.prototype = {
        say: function () {
            console.log("Hello");
        }
    }


    console.log(instance); //Class {extend: function}
    console.log(instance.say)
}

Class.extend = function () {
    this.prototype.extend();
}

Class.extend();
```